# Disassociating a runbook from a schedule

Tags: azure-automation, azure-runbook

Is there a way to disassociate a schedule from a runbook in the portal? Unless I'm missing something, you can only add a schedule to a runbook, but not remove it, unless the schedule itself is deleted. I know this can be done via PowerShell as follows:

```
Unregister-AzureRmAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName '<AccountName>' -RunbookName 'StartServiceFabricClusterNodes' -ScheduleName 'Daily7am' -ResourceGroupName '<ResourceGroup>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you navigate to the Runbook and select Schedules, you will see the Schedules that are associated with that Runbook. If you click on one of them, it will open the Schedule’s View blade. On the top, you will see command buttons. One of those will be a More button. If you click that, you will see additional buttons, one of which is a Unlink button.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuA7j.jpg)